# Drag MapBox map on different UIView (iOS)

Tags: uiview, transparent, mapbox, gestures, pass-through

Our UIView contains a MapBox map.  At certain moments during our apps lifespan we display a UIView on top of the Map.

This view had a transparant background and a couple of controls inside it. What we want is to be able to drag the map on the spots where the view is transparent. (It should basically pass through the gestures to the view below it..which is the map).

To get a basic picture of what we try to accomplish: think of a map and above it is a view which shows a big + sign. What we want is when we drag the actual sign...nothing happens. But when you drag in the empty corners, it should drag the map.

Any ideas how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `-[UIView userInteractionEnabled]` and set it to `NO` for the transparent view. Be sure to set it to `YES` for the control subviews. That should do the trick.